# htaccess - Can I add a RewriteCond to another RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

OK, I'll strip this back because it's either easy or not possible...

- URL = `www.example.com/foldername/`
- USER IP = `203.0.113.111`
- FOLDER ON SERVER = `/2030113111-foldername/`

### .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)?
RewriteCond ^%1%2%3%4-%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^. - [L,NC]
```

This would protect folder viewing unless the users IP was specific to the requested foldername and the IP-URI named folder existed.

Need a solution using HTACCESS specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `RewriteCond`s for just one `RewriteRule`. Just write the `RewriteCond`s underneath each other, e.g.

```
RewriteCond foo bar
RewriteCond bar foo
RewriteRule .* example.org
```

The RewriteRule will only execute if `foo == bar` and `bar == foo` is true (never). :)

Comment: OK, the line breaks aren't showing but...... Not really what I am looking for... I know you can stack and pass captured groups. I'd like to know if the second condition is possible... 

RewriteCond ^%1%2%3%4-%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

is effectively

RewriteCond ^255255255255-%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

so is there a folder called 255255255255-foldername on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like this, but not quite in the way you are doing it. You just need to use the correct server variables.

> ```
> RewriteCond ^%1%2%3%4-%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
> ```

The problem with this directive is that `REQUEST_FILENAME` is an absolute filesystem path. So, this effectively checks if `^2030113111-/home/user/public_html/foldername` is a valid directory - which is going to fail. The `TestString` is also a *string*, not a regular expression, so the `^` prefix is also going to break things.

Instead, you could do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%2%3%4-$1 -d
RewriteRule (.+) - [L]
```

Where `$1` is the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* is processed first, before, the `RewriteCond` directives that precede it.

In order to test what directory we are checking, you can assign this to an environment variable and check this in your script. So, for testing:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%2%3%4-$1 (.*)
RewriteRule (.+) - [E=DIRECTORY_CHECKING_FOR:%1,L]
```

Examine the `DIRECTING_CHECKING_FOR` environment variable in your script should show something like: `/home/user/public_html/2030113111-foldername`, depending on your filesystem structure.

Note that `%1` matches the *last matched* group in a preceding *CondPattern* (not necessarily the one immediately above if there are no matching groups). So, the `%1` in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* matches the `(.*)` (the entire "directory name" we are checking). Whereas `%1` in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* matches the first octet of the IP address.